# How can I visualize deviation from the standard as a badge?

Tags: icons, status, font-sizes, badge

I have an icon-button on my website. When clicking on it, the font size can be increased/decreased.

I want to visualize that there is a deviation from the normal font size when the user clicks to change font size. I thought of using a badge for that.

However, I can't find a good way to indicate this change.

**What should I display in the badge?** I can only use text, also ascii symbols. Should it be a plus or minus, whether the font size is bigger or smaller than usual. Or just a "1".

What do you think?

[image: Badge]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many examples of this in current apps, where it is either a function of a word processor or an accessibility feature.

A quick google brings back quite a few options:search?q=increase+text+size+accessibility

See here (at the bottom of the article) for Microsofts implementation.
https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Change-the-font-size-931e064e-f99f-4ba4-a1bf-8047a35552be?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB

---

The relavant asci symbols may exist to create something similar as seen below.

**A**↑ **A**↓ **A**↕

https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/arrows/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you could use something like:

[image: AAA]

or

[image: A]